# Scale histograms by a certain factor?

Tags: python, histogram, scale

I'm trying to represent three different data sets on the same histogram but one is 100 data points, one is 362 and one is 289. I'd like to scale the latter two by factors of 3.62 and 2.89 respectively so they don't overshadow the 100 point one. I feel like this should be easy but I'm not sure where to put my division. I feel like I've tried all the spots you can try. Here's how it is now:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
scale_pc = (1 / 3.62)  #this is the math I'd like to use, but where to put it?
scale_ar = (1 / 2.89)  #this is the math I'd like to use, but where to put it?

alldf2[alldf2['playlist']==1]['danceability'].hist(bins=35, color='orange', label='PopConnoisseur', alpha=0.6)
alldf2[alldf2['playlist']==2]['danceability'].hist(bins=35, color='green',label='Ambient',alpha=0.6)
alldf2[alldf2['playlist']==0]['danceability'].hist(bins=35, color='blue',label='Billboard',alpha=0.6)

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Danceability')
```

I've tried variations on this but none work:

```
alldf2[alldf2['playlist']==1]['danceability'].hist(bins=35, color='orange', label='PopConnoisseur', alpha=0.6)
alldf2[alldf2['playlist']==2]['danceability'/ 3.62].hist(bins=35, color='green',label='Ambient',alpha=0.6)
alldf2[alldf2['playlist']==0]['danceability'/ 2.89].hist(bins=35, color='blue',label='Billboard',alpha=0.6)
```

Any thoughts?

Edit: Here's the plot as it currently is:
[image: Danceability values per playlist]

Comment: Please make your example runnable by providing imports & the line where you've defined `alldf2`

Comment: you could set `density=True` when plotting each histogram - that makes the area under each one equal to 1, so they should all plot nicely together. Alternatively, you could supply `weights` to the histogram function, where the weights for playlist 2 is an array of the value (`1/3.62`), etc.

Comment: Thanks, tmdavison - "density=True" worked like a charm.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd one for sure won't work because it seems to have a syntax error here

```
'danceability'/ 3.62
```

in parenthesis you are calling the column I do not think that you can divide the values like that. Moreover, even if something like that would work it would probably divide your values in that column by 3.62, not return 100 data points...

Also I am not sure what is the problem with having more data points in the other histogram, that's kind of the thing which you want the histogram to show - i.e. how many elements are having a particular value.

Also, as Blazej said in the comment, give an example of data so we can understand a bit more what are you trying to do. Specify what you want to achieve by using just 100 points.